# Redirect output from subshell and processing through pipe at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

**tl;dr:** need a way to process (with grep) an output inside subshell AND redirect all original output to the main stdout/stderr at the same time. I am looking for shell-independent (!) way.

**In detail**

1. There is a proprietary binary which I want to grep for some value
2. The proprietary binary from time to time might be interactive to ask for a password (depends on the internal logic)
3. I want to grep the output of the binary AND want being able to enter the password it that is required to proceed further

So the script which is supposed to achieve my task might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
user_id=... # some calculated value

list_actions_cmd="./proprietary-binary --actions ${user_id}"
action_item=$(${list_actions_cmd} | grep '^Main:')
```

Here `proprietary-binary` might ask for a password through `stdin`. Since subshell inside `$()` catches the all output, an end-user won't understand that the `list_actions_cmd` waits for input. What I want is either to show all output of `list_action_cmd` AND grepping at the same time or at least caught the keyword that now user will be asked for a password and let him know about that.

Currently what I figured out is to `tee` the output and grep there:

```
#!/bin/sh
user_id=... # some calculated value

list_actions_cmd="./proprietary-binary --actions ${user_id}"
$list_actions_cmd 2>&1 | tee /tmp/.proprietary-binary.log
action_item=$(grep "^Main" /tmp/.proprietary-binary.log)
```

But I wonder is there any elegant shell-independent (not limited to bash which is quite powerful) solution without any intermediate temporary file? Thanks.

Comment: You should read [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @chepner, how reading would help me with the issue? "Reading FAQ" could be an universal answer for all questions. I took a look there but haven't found a pattern to solve my question.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question. It explains why `list_actions_cmd="..."` is the wrong approach to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about duplicating output to stderr if executed in a terminal:

```
item=$(your_command | tee /dev/stderr | grep 'regexp')
```